# glGenerateMipmap raises GL_INVALID_OPERATION on specific platform

Tags: opengl, mipmaps

I performed `glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` on a texture that used as FBO rendering target. It works well on several Windows computers, but when I test it on a Linux laptop with *Intel HD3000* graphics card, it raises GL_INVALID_OPERATION error.

I checked the program with AMD CodeXL. When this error raised, the `GL_TEXTURE_BINDING_2D` has correct value, and bounded texture has correct properties:

```
# of mipmaps: 10 levels;
dimensions: 600x520
internal format: GL_DEPTH_STENCIL;
GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER: GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR.
GL_TEXTURE_MIN_LOD: -1000
GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LOD: 1000
GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL: 0
GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL: 1000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems caused by generating mipmap on `DEPTH24_STENCIL8` texture. Temporarily I masked mipmap generation of all those depth-stencil textures, and all this kind of warnings eliminated.

Non-power-of-2 texture size does not looks like the cause, because I have many other same sized textures that works well.

I have known that the *Intel HD Graphics* Linux drivers have many limits, such as not support `#version 150` GLSL. And now I've got one more limit :)

Answer (score 0):

Your texture dimension is not power-of-two, see https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glGenerateMipmap.xml

> Errors
>
> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if either the width or height of the
>   zero level array is not a power of two.

To fix it, use a power-of-two texture, eg. 512x512 etc.

Comment: Not that problem. I have many non-power-of-2 textures in that program.

Comment: You're linking to the OpenGL ES 2.0 documentation. The desktop OpenGL docs for this function have no such limitation.